# Why do I get a PEP warning asking me to change my equality statement in that context?

Tags: python, pandas, pep

I have this line of code:

```
df['volume_up'] = np.where(df['trade_direction'] == True, df['volume'], float('nan'))
```

and I get this warning:

[image]

but if I change the statement to

```
df['trade_direction'] is True
```

it will not work anymore.

Why am I getting this warning? or am I implementing the change the wrong way?

Comment: I'd ignore it; your PEP8 analyzer just doesn't know numpy.

Comment: Just ignore it. `numpy` breaks the assumption that `==` returns a boolean object, thus that part of the PEP doesn't apply. Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to write a PEP8 analyzer that [prevents foolish consistency](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds).

Comment: You can use the second suggestion: `np.where(df['trade_direction'], df['volume'], float('nan'))` and it'll produce your expected results and quiet the linter

Comment: how would I go about handling the opposite (==False) case in a Numpy and PEP friendly way? (I have some lines with True, some with False)

Comment: You can use `~df['trade_direction']`